# Setter in view a from view b : unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Here is some code:

ViewControllerA.h

```
@interface ViewControllerA: UIViewController {
   NSString *myString;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain)NSString *myString;
```

ViewControllerA.m

```
@implementation ViewControllerA
@synthesize myString;
```

Then i push ViewControllerB in the navigationcontroller. When i want to return to ViewControllerA
ViewControllerB.m

```
-(IBAction)randomAction(id)sender {
   ViewControllerA *myViewController = (ViewControllerA*)[self parentViewController]:
   [myViewController setMyString:@"test"]: // HERE IS THE ERROR : "[DMINavigationController setMyString:]:unrecognized selector sent to instance"
   [self.navigationController popToViewController:[[self.navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES]
}
```

Why? Is it normal that error reffers to "[DMINavigationController setMyString:]" instead of my viewcontroller?

Comment: where setMyString method is defined?

Comment: isnt next supposed to be myString?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are a bit confused about ViewControllers and how to handle them properly in a NavigationController.

You probably started with an `DMINavigationController` and initialized it with an `ViewControllerA`. If you push a new ViewController `ViewControllerB`, the parent won't be `ViewControllerA` but rather the NavigationController.

If you want to access the previous ViewController you need to query the `viewControllers` property of your NavigationController to find it.

The VC you are looking for is at (index of current Object)-1

```
int index = [self.navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:self] - 1;
ViewControllerA *vcA = [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:index];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. I was confused about navigationController, thanks for explanations :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `myView` variable has been assigned to be your view controller's parent view controller, which is clearly not a `ViewA` instance due to the crash trying to send it a message declared by `ViewA`. Why are you doing that - what are you trying to accomplish with the parent?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `parentViewController` I think you intended [`presentingViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/presentingViewController). This is only available in iOS5 or later.

I see you've accepted another answer, which is great, but another approach is for view controller B to have a property that is weak reference to view controller A, which A would set after it creates B but before it transitions to B (e.g., in `prepareForSegue` if you're using segues).

Answer (score -1):

You can not set the string to a view. You have to create a label then set the text to label and one more thing you are not creating property for myString then how come you are setting

@synthesize myString;

If you are writing Property of variable then only you can add @synthesize.